# Programmatic Way To Link Text Within A PDF

Tags: php, pdf, coldfusion, acrobat

I am looking for some way to code a function (I'm open to any language or library at this point) to take an already existing PDF file as input and return a modified PDF file that links certain words to different URLs.  I know PHP and ColdFusion both have good tools for dealing with PDF's, but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

I've been doing this by going through Acrobat and linking the text by hand and was wondering if there was any way to automate the procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: I had success generating PDFs with fpdf several years ago: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: There are several good Perl modules for manipulating PDFs: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[perl]+pdf

Comment: In short - no. Sergii's suggestion is probably as close as you can get here. See: Can I Edit Pdf's: http://itextpdf.com/faq.php?branch=faq.pdf_in_general&node=replace_word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ColdFusion you can extract the text with [DDX](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/cfpdf_18.html#169955) (see *Extracting text from a PDF document* on the page), modify it using search/replace and generate new document.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should be able to use CFPDF (http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_p-q_02.html#2922772) to read the pdf file into a ColdFusion variable, replace whatever content you want in that variable, then save the content back to pdf.

Comment: Pdf's are binary files. So you cannot do a search and replace as you might with a text file.

Comment: Yes you can, once ColdFusion converts it into a variable.

Comment: Nope. Though you might not receive an error, it does not actually _work_. Try it and see for yourself. Pdf's just do not work that way.

Comment: In CF9, you can extract text from a PDF document, but you can't use `cfpdf` to replace the text within that document. Earlier versions of CF don't have the extractText task.